# What Is The Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll

Tags: c#, web-services, wse

Can someone explain what this does and why its needed?

Comment: Such question! Why not consult google instead?

Comment: Not sure what down vote is for. Question seems like a valid one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll belongs to Web Services Enhancements 2.0 for Microsoft .NET Framework

You might need it if working with or implementing additional WS-* web service specifications using the Microsoft Web Services Enhancements.

Read more on:

- [Wikipedia entry for Web Services Enhancements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Enhancements)

Answer (score 3):

> Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll belongs to
>   Web Services Enhancements 2.0 for
>   Microsoft .NET Framework

[Microsoft Thread on Web.Services2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/fe73b42d-28ae-409b-a8de-ce54bbd09075)